# Create image of Windows partition on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, backup, partition, hard-drive

I'd like to create an image of my Windows partition (so a can restore it later) and I was wondering if anyone could recommend any utilities that are capable of this? Either command line or GUI (pref. Gnome) would be OK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ntfsclone](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsclone) is awesome. I've used it with great success to clone systems and for backup purposes.

If your Windows partition is not using NTFS, dd should take care of you -- although it's not terribly efficient.

Comment: I've imaged many, many hundreds of Windows XP machines w/ ntfsclone. It's wonderful. BG Rescue Linux (http://www.giannone.eu/rescue/current/) is a nice packaged bootable CD distro that has the ntfsprogs built in.

Comment: Thanks for that link - my bootable rescue CD of choice has been System Rescue CD (http://www.sysresccd.org/) but I will probably check out BG Rescue now. Does it include an option to boot right into non-Linux utils like Ranish?

Comment: It's just a plain, vanilla CD (or floppy!) based rescue linux distro. It's helped me out quite a number of times.

Comment: Oh, yeah-- and it has "ms-sys" so that it can write Microsoft-compatible MBRs and boot sectors. Also a big win.

Answer (score 6):

dd would seem to be the go to choice here.  The command would look like the following...replace the device and output file with whatever you wish.

```
 dd if=/dev/sda1 of=~/windows.img
```

There is also partimage and ghost4linux.  But for something like this both of those may be overkill and overcomplicating things.

Comment: It'll do whitespace as well, so make sure you have enough space on your target.

Comment: I've tried Ghost4Linux - it's a little clunky to use and if you are backing up over the network it requires an FTP target - you can't save to a normal SMB fileshare!

Comment: about 'overkill': partimage does not save empty space on backup if it can figure out the filesystem type whereas dd does. In addition, partimage can zero out empty space on restore whereas dd can't

Answer (score 3):

### Partimage

Definitely a good option http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page.  You can create an image and  compressed it to save disk space, and they can be splitted into multiple files to be copied on CDs / DVDs.  Partitions can also be saved across the network.

Comment: Note that the partimage site linked says NTFS supported is experimental.  It recommends not turning on NTFS compression and defragging your filesystem before creating the image.

Comment: I've used it a bunch of times, never had a problem restoring other than having to be creative when it comes to restoring to a bigger HD.   Thanks for pointing it out though, I thought that by now they would have taken cared of any bugs with NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

And you'll probably need your master boot record too. the command will be something like:

> dd if=/dev/sda of=~/windows.mbr bs=512 count=1

That will give you your boot sector and your partition table. Take a look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-backup-hard-disk-partition-table-mbr.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

[clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) == an opensource version of ghost, works really well

Comment: I have bad memories of ghost...

Comment: clonezilla is a live cd with a bunch of utilities pushed together which includes ntfsclone, so same principle as ghost but completely different implementation